# PDO using bindValue() with optional values

Tags: php, pdo

I have a search form with three text inputs (trade, city, state). When performing a search, the user must fill in at least one of the fields but has the option to fill in all three. I have not finished yet, but here is the code I have so far to query the database:

```
 function query_database($person, $trade='', $city='', $state='') {
    include("connection.php");
    if($trade != " ") {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM $person WHERE trade1 LIKE :trade OR trade2 LIKE :trade OR trade3 LIKE :trade";
    }
    else if($city != " ") {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM $person WHERE city LIKE :city";  
    }
    else if($state != " ") {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM $person WHERE state LIKE :state";  
    }

    $results = $db->prepare($sql); 
        $results->bindValue(':city', $city);
        $results->bindValue(':state', $state);
        $results->bindValue(':trade', $trade);

    $results->execute();
        $data = $results->fetchAll();

        if($data) {
             print_r($data);
        }
```

To test this out, I called the function with the following parameters:

```
query_database('master_tradesmen', 'plumbing', ' ', ' ');
query_database('master_tradesmen', ' ', 'New York', ' ');
query_database('master_tradesmen', ' ', ' ', 'WI');
```

The first function call produced results, but the second two gave me the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Why does it work with $trade but not $city or $state? How do I get it to work on all three?

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward; it can't work with the others because they don't have three placeholders (you create queries with only one).

Comment: By the way, what exactly is the search logic? Can the user fill out two out of three fields? Your current logic will give you wrong results for some of the searches.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you! Yes, the user can fill in either one, two or all three. I still have 'if else' statements I need to add to make sure all search possibilities are covered. I just wanted to clear this hurdle first.

Comment: A more flexible solution https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `bindValue()`. The `execute()` method can take the values as an array of arguments. So create that array in the `if` blocks.

```
function query_database($person, $trade='', $city='', $state='') {
    include("connection.php");
    if($trade != " ") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $person WHERE trade1 LIKE :trade OR trade2 LIKE :trade OR trade3 LIKE :trade";
        $params = [':trade' => $trade];
    }
    elseif($city != " ") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $person WHERE city LIKE :city";
        $params = [':city' => $city];
    }
    elseif($state != " ") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $person WHERE state LIKE :state";  
        $params = [':state' => $state];
    }

    $results = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $results->execute($params);
    $data = $results->fetchAll();

    if($data) {
        print_r($data);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that rapid reply. Just what I needed!